# How i change custom input in TextEdit Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, textedit

I have the TextEdit with properties max value = 6, the default value is "000000"
and i will replace the value according to user input. For example when user input "69" in TextEdit, the final value TextEdit to be "000069". How i prepare that using c# ?

Please help me to prepare that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (add EditValueChanging event handler to your text edit):

```
    private void textEdit_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        const int MaxLength = 6;
        var editor = (DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit)sender;

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var s = (string)e.NewValue;
            s = s.TrimStart('0');

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) == false)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    editor.Text = s.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, MaxLength)).PadLeft(MaxLength, '0');
                    editor.SelectionStart = MaxLength;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Stefano , but the method just change one string in last... how to handle it when i input some value? for example when i input "69" then the value change to "000069", and when input "696" and the value show "000696"..

Comment: The method fires on value changing, not on value changed. Must be work every time you insert a new character, is not?

Comment: oh i see... why my input only once, because I determine the length of its value. i set the maxsimum value = 6. so when i input value again not change. When i not set maxsimun value, the method working perfectly, thanks... but how i handle the method "textEdit_EditValueChanging" when the length value have 6, user cannot input value again?

Comment: I edit the code above.
Not use MaxLength in designer (set it to 0)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Edit Mask on TextEdit control. To achieve required functionality you can set the [TextEdit.Properties.Mask.MaskType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMaskMaskProperties_MaskTypetopic) property to to [Simple](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1500/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Concepts/Masks/Mask-Type-Simple) and set the [TextEdit.Properties.Mask.EditMask](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMaskMaskProperties_EditMasktopic) property to "000000".

Go through documentation - [Mask Editors Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/583/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Concepts/Masks/Mask-Editors-Overview)

> To enable the **Simple** masked mode set the [MaskProperties.MaskType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskProperties.MaskType.property)
>   property of the [RepositoryItemTextEdit.Mask](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit.Mask.property) object to [MaskType.Simple](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.enum).
>   The mask itself should be specified via the [MaskProperties.EditMask](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskProperties.EditMask.property)
>   property.

**Example:**

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "000000";
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Simple;
```

If you do not want to mask the editor control then go for [Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/587/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Concepts/Formatting-and-Parsing/Formatting), Here is an example:
[How to: Add Custom Text to a Formatted String](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2146/Common-Features/Formatting-Values/How-to-Add-Custom-Text-to-a-Formatted-String)

```
textEdit1.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
textEdit1.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "{0:d6}";
```

Hope this help

Comment: hey thank @Niranjan , but when i using Edit Mask just show error information. 
I want it when the user enters though two values, it will be recorded with the default value that exists. like : when user input "69" in TextEdit, the value can be 000069...

Comment: Have tried to set this as DisplayMask. I have updated answer with reference links. Hope this help

Comment: Yes i have tried it, when i press enter in TextEdit, the value not change to "000069" when i just input value "69" in TextEdit.. The TextEdit just show "69______".  is there may be something wrong from my step?